# Inconsistent tab behaviour with ngGrid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm facing some inconsistent behaviour when the tab key when attempting to implement an `ngGrid` that allows the user to edit some of the cells.

The problem is that the tab key does not move me to the next field if I select the input field without first having selected the entire row.

Is there a way to get the required functionality without explicitly trying to select the row on focus of the input control?

You can see the `plunkr` [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HFqB2c0nbLdaAAxP4GG9).

Here is the markup:

```
<body ng-controller='myCntrl' >
<h1>Unable to Tab across input fields</h1>
<div class='gridStyle' ng-grid="model.gridOptions"></div>
```

And the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',['ngGrid']);

    app.controller('myCntrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.model.data = [{field1: 1,field2: 2,field3: 3 },{field1:4,field2: 5,field3:6 }];

    $scope.model.gridOptions = {
       data: 'model.data',
       enableCellSelection: true,

       columnDefs: [
            { field: 'field1', displayName: 'Field 1', width: '*', cellTemplate: '<input ng-required="true" type="number" ng-model="COL_FIELD" ng-input="COL_FIELD">' },
            { field: 'field2', displayName: 'Field 2', width: '*', cellTemplate: '<input ng-required="true"  type="number" ng-model="COL_FIELD" ng-input="COL_FIELD">' },
            { field: 'field3', displayName: 'Field 3', width: '*', cellTemplate: '<input ng-required="true"  type="number" ng-model="COL_FIELD" ng-input="COL_FIELD">' }
       ]
    };
});
```